# Импорт пакетов, с имени пакета по шаблону

Tags: java, импорт

Есть пакет: `net.minecraft.server.**v1_12_R1**.DedicatedServer`
Но проблема в том, что в каждой версий ядра, `v1_12_R1` меняется на что-то другое, но сама структура дальше одинаковая. То есть, мне нужно импортировать пакет, по такому шаблону: `net.minecraft.server.*.DedicatedServer`

Скорее всего такое не возможно в Java, но всё же, вдруг.

Спасибо!

Comment: Вы не хотите при сборке новых версий исправлять импорты руками?

Comment: это плагин, и он должен работать на многих версиях ядра. По факту там нечего и не меняют, в том классе в который я лезу ещё с времен первого ядра.

Comment: @АнастасияСафонова , вы правы, напрямую такое невозможно. "Всё же" есть варианты, но для этого вам придется приоткрыть завесу тайны: каким образом вы используете этот класс в вашем коде? Достаточно ли динамически загрузить его или же вы интенсивно используете его?

Comment: @Ramiz , [Главный класс](https://pastebin.com/KTJ0GKeM), [UDPServer](https://pastebin.com/EgNi8xYp), [Шаблон класса, каждой версий](https://pastebin.com/daZNxnDJ) - Ну вот что-то такое сейчас

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на основании известной информации (надеюсь вы прикрепите исходники к вопросу, потому что в комментариях их сложнее найти тем кто столкнется с подобной проблемой) думаю можно вполне обойтись стандартной рефлексией. Т.о. выглядеть это будет как-то так:

```
public void onLoad() {
    try {
        String packageName = getServer().getClass().getPackage().getName();
        Class<?> minecraftServerClass = Class.forName(packageName + ".MinecraftServer");
        Method getServer = minecraftServerClass.getMethod("getServer");
        Object dedicateServer = getServer.invoke(minecraftServerClass);
        Field propertyManagerField = dedicateServer.getClass().getField("propertyManager");
        Object propertyManager = propertyManagerField.get(dedicateServer);
        Method setProperty = propertyManager.getClass().getMethod("setProperty", String.class, boolean.class);
        setProperty.invoke(propertyManager, "enable-query", false);
    } catch(SecurityException | ReflectiveOperationException ex) {
        // TODO replace with proper logger or error handling
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Это был прямой перевод вашего кода без оптимизации. Если же getServer возвращает экземпляр DedicateServer, то первые четыре строки сводятся к одной:

```
Object dedicatedServer = getServer();
```